# Best way to render component when state is updated?

Tags: reactjs

I have a functional component in which I add a object to my localStorage:

```
const AddMovieToLocalStorage = async (movie) => {
  const value = await localforage.getItem<string []>('trackedMovies');
  value.push(movie.movieData);
  localforage.setItem('trackedMovies', value)
}
```

In a different component from a different tree I render a list based on the local storage key:

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    data: []
  }
}

getData = async () => {
  const trackedMovies = await localforage.getItem<[]>('trackedMovies'); 

  this.setState({
    data: trackedMovies
  })
}

componentDidMount = () => {
  this.getData()
}

render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      { this.state.data.map(movie => {
        return (
          <li key={movie.id}>{movie.original_title}</li>
        )
      })}
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

The components are separated from each other in different trees.

Comment: i think you should use a reducer between your "localForage" and your components.  Also you should use the actual state management mechanisms like getState and useState.  lastly you should think of a more robust way to handle this... maybe Redux or MobX???

Comment: The local storage is going to be replaced with aan actual db ay some point. I think maybe the context API could work here.

Comment: You still need a layer of abstraction... That is why React has useReducer, useState hooks in the case of function components and and getState, setState in the case of class components.  But you need to go further and use for example Redux or MobX

Comment: You could use the context hook.... but i am not sure how that would work with a class component.

Comment: Wel I could make it a functional component.I just started React this week so I still need to learn a lot. Gonna check something like reducer out.